# I have a problem with VerticalTimelineElement's attribute icon

Tags: reactjs

I want to automate the creation of element components in a VerticalTimeline in react.
I'm a beginner in react and I got an error that I can't really find the answer to. I probably made a typo.

```
import SchoolIcon from "@material-ui/icons/School";
import WorkIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Work";
```

I passed the above, all code works if I insert `<SchoolIcon/>` manually for example.

Here is an example of array from where I extract details for component's properties:

```
const data=[
{
    timelineType: "education" / "work",
    dateValue: "01/2020 - 09-2021", 
    titleValue: "example",
    subtitleValue: "example or nothing",
    paragraphValue: "paragraph example",
},
];
```

Everything works except for **iconValue**. I tried 2 methods, but without success.
Here is my code:

```
const TimelineItem = ({
  timelineType,
  dateValue,
  titleValue,
  subtitleValue,
  paragraphValue,
}) => {
  let iconStyleValue, iconValue, ifSubtitleValue;
  if (timelineType === "education") {
    iconStyleValue = `background: "#3e497a", color: "#fff"`;
    iconValue = `SchoolIcon`;
  }
  if (timelineType === "work") {
    iconStyleValue = `background: "#e9d35b", color: "#fff"`;
    iconValue = `WorkIcon`;
  }
  if (subtitleValue) {
    ifSubtitleValue = (
      <h4 className="vertical-timeline-element-subtitle">{subtitleValue}</h4>
    );
  }

  function typeOfIcon(){
    console.log("icon")
    iconValue === "SchoolIcon" ? <SchoolIcon/> : <WorkIcon/>
  }

  return (
      <VerticalTimelineElement
        className={`vertical-timeline-element--${timelineType}`}
        date={ dateValue }
        iconStyle={{ iconStyleValue }}
        icon={typeOfIcon()}
        // icon={ <${iconValue}/> }
      >
        <h3 className="vertical-timeline-element-title">{titleValue}</h3>
        {ifSubtitleValue}
        <p>{paragraphValue}</p>
      </VerticalTimelineElement>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem

```
const TimelineItem = ({
  timelineType,
  dateValue,
  titleValue,
  subtitleValue,
  paragraphValue,
}) => {
  let backgroundColorStyle, colorStyle, iconValue, ifSubtitleValue;
  if (timelineType === "education") {
    backgroundColorStyle = "#3e497a"
    colorStyle = "#fff"
    iconValue = <SchoolIcon/>;
  }
  if (timelineType === "work") {
    backgroundColorStyle = "#e9d35b"
    colorStyle = "#fff"
    iconValue = <WorkIcon/>;
  }
  if (subtitleValue) {
    ifSubtitleValue = (
      <h4 className="vertical-timeline-element-subtitle">{subtitleValue}</h4>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <VerticalTimelineElement
        className={`vertical-timeline-element--${timelineType}`}
        date={ dateValue }
        iconStyle={{ background: backgroundColorStyle, color: colorStyle }}
        icon={ iconValue }
        >
        <h3 className="vertical-timeline-element-title">{titleValue}</h3>
        {ifSubtitleValue}
        <p>{paragraphValue}</p>
      </VerticalTimelineElement>
    </>
  );
};
```